# Solve the differential equation $(x+1)^2y''-2(x+1)y'+2y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $$(x+1)^2y''-2(x+1)y'+2y=0$$

My attemp:
sub. $x+1=u$
after this substitution the above equation takes form
$$u^2y''-2uy'+2y=0$$
This equation is of the form $ax^2y''+bxy'+cy=0$-which solution is $ar^2+(b-a)r+c=0.$ According to this for our equation we have $a=1,b=-2,c=2$

Now i have
$$ar^2-2r+2=0$$
Solution of end equation is $r=1\pm i,$  where $\alpha =1, \beta=1$

Solution is:
$$y_{H}=C_1u\cos(\ln x)+C_2u\sin(\ln x)=C_1(x+1)\cos(\ln x)+C_2(x+1)\sin(\ln x)$$
But i didnt now its the correct answer.Tell me please.

Comment: "Where $a=1,\,b=-2,\,c=2$" Please update your question to clarify which family of ODEs you've parameterized.

Comment: equation $u^2y''-2uy'+2y=0$ is it eqution of form $ax^2y''+bxy'+cy=0$-Couchy-Euler form

Comment: Another possibility is also to derivate the initial ODE again to arrive to $y'''=0$, introducing a spurious constant though, but I feel that's kind of cheating at the solution and retro-engineering the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is wrong, $u^2y''-2uy'+2y=0$ is not an ODE with constant coefficients, so you cannot use the characteristic equation directly like this.

Fortunately in the case of $u^py^{(p)}$ groups where $y^{(p)}$ denotes the $p-$derivarive, and $x^p$ powers of $x$ with the **same $p$** then the substitution $y=f(\ln(u))$ makes things pretty.

$\begin{cases}y=f(\ln(u))\\
y'=\frac 1uf'(\ln(u))\\
y''=\frac {-1}{u^2}f'(\ln(u))+\frac 1{u^2}f''(\ln(u))\end{cases}$

Let set $t=\ln(u)$ and then $\Big(-f'(t)+f''(t)\Big)-2f'(t)+2f(t)=0$

Your ODE is transformed to a linear one with constant coefficients

$$f''(t)-3f'(t)+2f(t)=0$$

Characteristic equation is $r^2-3r+2=(r-1)(r-2)$ and we have $f(t)=Ae^t+Be^{2t}$

Substituting back $t=\ln(u)$ and $u=x+1$ you get

$$y(x)=A(x+1)^2+B(x+1)$$

Comment: how find the equation $f''-3f'+2=0$

Comment: I am not very clear in your answer

Comment: It is just substitution. $y=f(\ln(u))$ then $y'=\frac 1uf'(\ln(u))$ and $y''=...$ then cancel out the $u^2$ factor and you are left with what I wrote with $t=\ln(u)$.

Comment: I made the substitutions you said, but it does not work $f''-3f'+2=0$ but $f''+2f'+2=0$ please check again @zwim

Comment: Did you do the product rule correctly ? See my edit, $y''$ has two terms.

Comment: now clearly, thanks sir, thanks for help me, and for your attention

Answer (score 2):

$$(x+1)^2y''-2(x+1)y'+2y=0$$
Rewrite it as;
$$y''-2\dfrac {(x+1)y'-y}{(x+1)^2}=0$$
$$y''-2\left (\dfrac {y}{x+1}\right)'=0$$
And integrate.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: define $z:=y/u$ so$$y=uz\implies y^\prime=uz^\prime+z,\,y^{\prime\prime}=uz^{\prime\prime}+2z^\prime\implies0=u^2y^{\prime\prime}-2uy^\prime+2y=u^3z^{\prime\prime}.$$

Comment: and how to continue this

Comment: @hihi Can you solve $z^{\prime\prime}=0$? Can you restate that with $y=uz$?

Comment: i.e. my attemp is not correct